# How to have a condition in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to load a bootstrap modal on page load unless a cancel button is pressed. The way the functionality is supposed to work is that once page loads, wait 2 seconds and show the modal, unless a cancel button is pressed, in that case the modal should not show, however the modal shows regardless of the cancel button pressed,

```
const Call = ({ t, i18n }) => {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [cancelCall, setCancelCall] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (cancelCall) {
       return;
     } else {
       setTimeout(() => {
         setModalShow(true);
       }, 2000);
     }
  }, [setModalShow, cancelCall]);

  const handleCancelCall = e => {
    setCancelCall(true);
    console.log("cancel call pressed!");
  };

return (
    <Fragment>
      <CallModal show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />

    <button
            type="button"
            className="ml-4 btn btn-light"
            onClick={e => handleCancelCall()}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
      </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why modal should disappear when `modalShow` is still `true`?

Comment: I don't need to modal to appear at all, if the cancel button is pressed before the 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Rajesh's answer works, it's causing 2 unnecessary re-renders (calling `setTimer`). I would recommend you simply keep track of the timer using a `ref` instead

```
const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
const modalTimer = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  // the if (cancelCall) part in here was pointless 
  // because initial state is always false
  modalTimer.current = setTimeout(() => setModalShow(true), 2000);
}, []);

const handleCancelCall = e => {
  // on cancel, simply clear the timer
  modalTimer.current && clearTimeout(modalTimer.current);
};
```

The above also removes some redundant code & state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think this a more efficient way of doing it, so I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is because, on page load, your `cancelCall` will always be false and so you will register a timeout event.

Post that user clicks the button but the registered event needs to be removed as well. Try:

```js
const Call = ({ t, i18n }) => {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [cancelCall, setCancelCall] = useState(false);

  // Save the timer id in state
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (cancelCall) {
       return;
     } else {
       const timer = setTimeout(() => {
         setModalShow(true);
       }, 2000);
       setTimer(timer)
     }
  }, [setModalShow, cancelCall]);

  const handleCancelCall = e => {
    setCancelCall(true);

    // On cancel, check if timer is not null. If not clear the timer from queue
    !!timer && window.clearTimeout(timer);
    setTimer(null)
    console.log("cancel call pressed!");
  };

return (
    <Fragment>
      <CallModal show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />

    <button
            type="button"
            className="ml-4 btn btn-light"
            onClick={e => handleCancelCall()}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
      </Fragment>
  );
};
```